# Remote host closed connection during handshake when doing HTTP POST

Tags: java, ssl, raspberry-pi3

I am writing a java application on Raspberry PI that gets data from my backend server doing a post request as an AJAX call. Randomly I get `Remote host closed connection during handshake` error. I checked the TLS version of my backend and raspberry pi and they both match. Can someone help me fix this issue? Here is the configuration I am using

```
OpenJDK 8

Raspberry Pi

Spark web framework
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was the issue with the inbuilt jetty web server of spark. I have updated the spark framework to the latest version which has an updated jetty server and it fixed this issue for me.